# Docker: how to connect to a service that is linked only

Tags: docker

I'm using the [Postgres image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) that uses `VOLUME` to store data and doesn't expose ports to the outside but requires linking to connect to.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can connect to this from the host machine using apps that require me to specify the host and port of the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Postgres image you linked to does `EXPOSE 5432` in the Dockerfile definition

So if you used `-P` in your `docker run` it would expose it automatically, however that would map it to a random port on your Docker host

What you probably want is to use something like

`docker run -d -p :5432:5432 --name=postgres postgres`

Which would expose and map the containers port 5432 to your docker hosts port 5432